# Stop VIM backup file on only one file

Tags: backup, vim, vimrc

Is it possible to stop VIM from automatically creating a backup for only a specific file?

I have a running todo list I keep on my desktop, and I don't get any use out of the ~todo that constantly appears.

I do, however, wish to keep the backup function for all other files though...is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
autocmd BufRead ~/Desktop/todo setl nobackup
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set backupskip=$HOME/Desktop/todo
```

Comment: that, along with variants of $HOME, did not work